# TypeScript 2.6.1 error TS2554: Expected 2-3 arguments, but got 1

Tags: angular, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have this error in angularjs5,

src/app/search/job.search.ts(17,10): error TS2554: Expected 2-3 arguments, but got 1.
src/app/search/job.search.ts(21,10): error TS2554: Expected 2-3 arguments, but got 1.

This is my code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()

export class JobSearch{

constructor(private _http: Http){}

private _jobListUrl = 'https://api.shiftjobapp.com/api/v3/job_list?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjIzMjQsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6XC9cL2FwaS5zaGlmdGpvYmFwcC5jb21cL2FwaVwvdjNcL2F1dGhlbnRpY2F0ZV9qb2Jfc2Vla2VyIiwiaWF0IjoxNTEyMzY3OTg1LCJleHAiOjE1MTMyMzE5ODUsIm5iZiI6MTUxMjM2Nzk4NSwianRpIjoiMWQ4NmZkZDYzZDI3YmFiODE0NjA5OTRjOGZhYjI4NTUifQ.3EzNsu154q7a6xFuhQSakBlC-rj1D0HZqLiuwHblNao';

private _jobDetailsUrl = 'https://api.shiftjobapp.com/api/v3/job_detailed?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjIzMjQsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6XC9cL2FwaS5zaGlmdGpvYmFwcC5jb21cL2FwaVwvdjNcL2F1dGhlbnRpY2F0ZV9qb2Jfc2Vla2VyIiwiaWF0IjoxNTEyMzY3OTg1LCJleHAiOjE1MTMyMzE5ODUsIm5iZiI6MTUxMjM2Nzk4NSwianRpIjoiMWQ4NmZkZDYzZDI3YmFiODE0NjA5OTRjOGZhYjI4NTUifQ.3EzNsu154q7a6xFuhQSakBlC-rj1D0HZqLiuwHblNao';   

getJobs(){
    return this._http.post(this._jobListUrl)
        .map((response:Response) => response.json());
}
getJobDetails(){
    return this._http.post(this._jobDetailsUrl)
        .map((response:Response) => response.json());
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

A `POST` request requires data

See for example

```
  addHero (hero: Hero): Observable<Hero> {
    return this.http.post<Hero>(this.heroesUrl, hero, httpOptions).pipe(
      tap((hero: Hero) => this.log(`added hero w/ id=${hero.id}`)),
      catchError(this.handleError<Hero>('addHero'))
    );
  }
```

from https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6